# Could number of docker containers be limited by file IO inside containers?

Tags: mysql, performance, docker

I am trying to stuff as many lamp stack containers inside docker as possible that are running wordpress. According to many sources it is possible to stuff over 500 containers on a docker server, for example:

- [Is there a maximum number of containers running on a Docker host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799382/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-containers-running-on-a-docker-host/21801470#21801470)

However, they most likely discuss empty docker containers and not LAMP stack ones (apache+mysql).

I have managed to stuff 120 containers running wordpress and don't see a siginifcant issue with RAM or CPU. I should be able to fit more but performance goes downhill in response times after that point.

A colleague has mentioned that mysql performs significant I/O operations which could cause issues with file descriptors / open file limits / and  fs.io.max.nr .

Could this be the case? Could it be that the number of open files of each containers limits the total number of containers?

Comment: Have you checked the things your colleague has suggested? For instance, have you run `df -i` to see if you are running out of inodes?

Comment: You should look at https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/ and http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf and keep in mind your host has some limit liek I/O bandwith, CPU...