# Effiicient and low-resource language for data simulation

Tags: docker, optimization, architecture, distributed

Our task is to create multi-instance simulator for sending changing data structure. Simulator should have up to 25.000 isolated instances, so all languages that require additional memory and space for enviroment (like Java) are not considered. Could we do this in different way than with Docker and C/C++?

Comment: Way too broad. It's unclear what an instance is. It could be a function, an object/class or some process (and much more). Also: i don't see any use-case for docker here (and it basically conflicts with your additional space requirement).

Comment: Instance represents one network device. Each device in real life is separated from each other by a few miles.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799382/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-containers-running-on-a-docker-host is relevant here even though some of this might be slightly out of date.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a scripting language like Python or Node.js for this purpose, you wouldn't need to install much on your base Docker Image for either.

Comment: While I love node and python, they add too much memory overhead in cases like this.